# How to replace/convert a current text to the desirable form?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

In mySQL I have saved in a column `seasons` the row `Autumn, Spring`

However on the fronted I have to convert it to

`'Autumn', 'Summer'`

as below

`$('.seed_season').selectpicker('val', ['Autumn', 'Summer']);`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You must be fetching the data and set the values by `PHP` I think? If yes add those code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are getting the row value by using `PHP / MYSQL` than you can use like that:

```
$DBvalue = 'Autumn,Spring';
$exploded = explode(",", $DBvalue);

$newString = "'".implode("','", $exploded)."'";
echo $newString; // 'Autumn','Spring'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that in the front-end you could use:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var formerStr ='Autumn, Summer';
  console.log('former string',formerStr);

  var res = formerStr.split(",");
  var newStr = '';
  res.forEach(function(entry) {
      newStr += "'"+entry+"',";
});
  newStr = newStr.slice(0, -1);
  console.log('final string',newStr);
});
```